# Free VPN software to browse from USA

Tags: windows, vpn, utility

What is the best free VPN I can use to browse the internet as I where from USA ?

I am on Windows 10

Comment: This isn't asking for any software, but for a service. Seems off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Windscribe](https://windscribe.com) which is free as long as you only use it for 10Gb per month. Typically I only activate it when browing sites or content that are not availible in my country and leave it off the rest of the time, so 10Gb is more than enough if this is the way you intend to use your VPN. Windscribe is very efficient and its use very straightforward, and I feel no difference in terms of speed.

If you want your VPN to be always on, Windscribe's 10Gb most certainly won't be enough. You could try using [Spotflux](http://www.spotflux.com) or [Betternet](https://www.betternet.co/), although I never tried them.